# Java | JFrame -> JCombobox : Getting Object(value) by using getSelectedItem?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I'm new to this and I need your help:

I've made a JCombobox with some content.
For the content I've used a method including name and value.
By referring to the Object(name) I've achieved to display the correct name.
Now i want to use JCombobox.getSelectedItem().Object(name) or something like that to get the value of the specific item - but it doesn't work.

Once again, I'm new to this and grateful for any kind of advice ;)

Heres the code:

```
JComboBox cb_cartype = new JComboBox();
cb_cartype.setBounds(229, 21, 184, 22);
panel.add(cb_cartype);
cb_cartype.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
cb_cartype.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {InsertMethodHere(name)}));


public String InsertMethodHere(String name) {
    name = "Normales Taxi";
    double value = 0.5;
    return name;
}
```

and later on i want something like this:

```
double safe = cb_cartype.getSelectedItem().InsertMethodHere(name)
```

or anything similiar to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Combobox With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for information about this process.

Basically you need to:

1. Create a custom Object to store the name and value data. You can add this object to the combo box model.
2. Create a custom renderer to display only the name in the combo box
3. Create your ActionListener to access the data from the custom object.

You can do each step individually or use the class provided to help simplify the process.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that ;) I guess that'll help me out ;)

Comment: @Slajoc, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

i have no solution for you 
but if i were you, i will definitely switch to JAVAFX 
**Why ?** Swing is out of date, last summer i made an entire project with it 
and believe the result was awful the GUI keeps freezing, ugly looking and list goes on, sorry for wasting your time to read this even if it wont help you solving your current problem, but its just an advice to you :)

Comment: (1-)this is not an answer. `i made an entire project with it and believe the result was awful the GUI keeps freezing,` - Don't blame Swing for your lack of Swing knowledge.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the JavaFx solution. But for school purposes I have to stick to swing - sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: sorry, its not important its just a quick advice

Comment: camickr- Yup i have to admit, i was a bad coder then, and probably i'm steel, but i didn't know the threading until a few months later, which could help me out to speed up my GUI
but you kind of have to admit, i mean com on the swing is out of date, it looks like GUI from lisa back in 80-90.
its dead now, oracle uses JavaFX as default library for building gui, since java7 got released javafx come with it, and up to this moment the javafx as i say " its the default.:)"